# Loading page after displaying the Unity logo at the beginning of the game

Tags: c#

I plan to open the banner immediately after the player opens the game and the Unity logo is seen and display it for a while and then enter the game. Please help me how to put my banner?

I expect this answer to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If by banner you mean a title screen / main menu, then you just need to create a Scene for it. Not exactly sure what else you're asking here.

For creating a scene: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/scenes-working-with.html

For creating specifically a title screen, there's plenty of YouTube tutorials to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit -> Project settings -> player

Then navigate to Splash Image -> splash screen

You can then add any image you like and modify how long is it onscreen for

[Here is the docs page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsSplashScreen.html)